# Sawtooth supply chain application setup failed

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

Step 1/11 : FROM hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:nightly
ERROR: Service 'shell' failed to build: manifest for hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:nightly not found

I am trying to build the supply chain application on linux environment but the build is failing.

Comment: Try using a stable version

Comment: @FrankC. yes i am using stable version only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hyperledger Sawtooth Supply Chain has been modified for the nightly build, 1.2, which is not released yet.  What I do is revert to the version that supports the current Sawtooth release, Sawtooth 1.1:

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain
cd sawtooth-supply-chain
git diff 50c404c >bionic.patch
patch --dry-run -R -p1 <bionic.patch
patch           -R -p1 <bionic.patch
sudo docker-compose up
```

Another solution that I have seen but have not tried, are a few Dockerfile tweeks:

```
    diff --git a/shell/Dockerfile b/shell/Dockerfile
    index 7ea0caba..b57c2db1 100644
    --- a/shell/Dockerfile
    +++ b/shell/Dockerfile
    @@ -13,10 +13,10 @@
     # limitations under the License.
     # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -FROM hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:nightly
    +FROM hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:bumper-nightly

     # Install Python, Node.js, and Ubuntu dependencies
    -RUN echo "deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable bionic universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    +RUN echo "deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/nightly xenial universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
       && (apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 44FC67F19B2466EA \
       || apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 44FC67F19B2466EA) \
       && apt-get update \

You can also ask these questions on the Sawtooth Supply Chain chat channel (free registration with The Linux Foundation):

https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth-supply-chain
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Anderson the above solution worked and it move forward but it failed again while creating supply shell.

Comment: In file `shell/Dockerfile` change `nightly` to `latest` and `bionic` to `xenial` on the second line (if the changes are not there)